# Referential integrity where multiple allocations in each table?

Tags: sql, referential-integrity

Ok so, I have a Projects Table and an Employees Table. First I keep getting very confused how I should set up the PK and FK in general.

I have Customers table and I want it so 1 customer can have multiple Projects at a time. So the solution is to put CustomerId into the Projects table and make it a foreign key right?

So the problem is, I want multiple employees to be a part of projects at any given time, and obviously each Project will need multiple employees. How do I set up Referential Integrity between them?

Comment: Many-to-many relations are usually implemented with the help of a separate link table.

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional table, `ProjectsEmployees`.  It will have a foreign key relationship to both `Projects` and to `Employees`.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a buffer table which contain `Foreign Key` to both `Employee` and `Project` table to make a `many-to-many` relationship. Example:

```
Table: ProjectAssign
PK: ProjectAssignId
FK: EmployeeId
FK: ProjectId
Unique Constraint: EmployeeId & ProjectId
```

This way you can have `many-to-many` relationship between `employee` and `project`. Unique constraint to make sure you don't have redundant data.

**Note**

You can also apply `composite key` to `EmployeeId` and `ProjectId`, but I think it's not a good idea

Answer (score 0):

So you have 1 Project that can relate to multiple employees and multiple customers at once.
So the Project table is your main table.
You can add the ID of the project table as FK in both Employee and Customer tables.
Also, the combination of the ID column can be used as a PI in order to have evenly row distribution among the AMPs.
Those tables are dimensional tables and I guess it won't be millions of rows large so you don't need another relational table to store the keys. 
The Project table will join with both Employee and Customer tables through "one to many" relation.
The Employee and Customer tables will join with the Project table through "many to one" relation.

There is some pic of what I mean.
[image]
I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of many-many relationships are handled through bridge table.

You can have a bridge table, which maintains, for each customer, there will be multiple projects, and each project can have multiple employees contributing to it.

**CustomerProjectEmployee**

```
+-------------+------------+-------------+
| CustomerID  | ProjectID  | EmployeeID  |
+-------------+------------+-------------+
|           1 |          1 |           1 |
|           1 |          2 |           1 |
|           1 |          3 |           1 |
|           1 |          1 |           2 |
|           1 |          2 |           2 |
|           1 |          3 |           2 |
+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

Here, for projects(1,2,3) of customerID(1), Employees(1,2) are contributing.